# Why do I get a trailing '1' after Perl's printf output?

Tags: perl, printf

When I implement the code below I get the correct dates:

```
10/05/2008
10/05/2009
```

When I use `printf` instead of `sprintf`, I get the following:

```
10/05/200910/05/20081
1
```

Any ideas on why `printf` prints the trailing `1`?

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my ($from_date, $to_date) = to_from_dates();

print "$from_date\n";
print "$to_date\n";

sub to_from_dates {
    my ($day, $month, $year) = (localtime)[3,4,5];
    my $to_date   = sprintf "%02d/%02d/%04d", $month+1, $day, $year+1900;
    my $from_date = sprintf "%02d/%02d/%04d", $month+1, $day, $year+1899;
    return ($from_date, $to_date);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `&` to invoke a sub unless you know what it does and you specifically need that behavior. Instead, use `to_from_dates()`.

Comment: Oooh, interesting. I always thought that the "&" was an optional character. It's not? It does something else? I believe I feel another StackOverflow question coming.

Comment: @Wilkie it might be time for you to read the docs then. They are on your computer: `perldoc perlsub`. (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)

Comment: Thanks loads Sinan! Rarely does a time go by when I haven't learned something from one of your posts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only [`sprintf`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#sprintf) *returns* a printable value. [`printf`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#printf) *prints* the value and returns `1` to tell you that output was a success.

The output you show is exactly the output I would expect if you were simply to erase the `s`-es from the beginning of the calls.

```
sub to_from_dates {
    my ($day, $month, $year) = (localtime)[3,4,5];
    my $to_date=printf("%02d/%02d/%04d", $month+1, $day, $year+1900);
    # printed: 10/05/2009 (no carriage return)
    # $to_date = '1';
    my $from_date=printf("%02d/%02d/%04d", $month+1, $day, $year+1899);
    # printed: 10/05/2008 (no carriage return)
    # $from_date = '1';
    return ($from_date,$to_date);
}

($from_date,$to_date)=to_from_dates(); # returns ( 1, 1 )
# output: 10/05/200910/05/2008
print $from_date."\n";                 # prints "1\n"; <- first line feed
# output: 10/05/200910/05/20081\n
print $to_date."\n";                   # prints "1\n"; <- second line feed.
# output: 10/05/200910/05/20081\n1\n
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use printf, Perl prints the line and returns the result of the operation which is 1, then you print this result, this is where ones come from. You can do either `printf` or `print sprintf`

Comment: No, ***please*** don't do `printf sprintf`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) returns a string, [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) prints to a filehandle (`STDOUT` by default) and returns `1` if it was successful.

So when you use `printf`, both dates are being printed on the screen while executing `to_from_dates` and then `print` statements print result of `to_from_dates` which is always (1, 1) as both `printf` statements were successful.